# Рекомендованное максимальное число файлов в папке (чтобы не тормозило)

Tags: php, linux

Какое максимальное число файлов рекомендовано хранить в папке чтобы доступ к файлам не замедлялся?

Число папок на скорость не влияет как файлов?

Comment: вы скерьезно хотите их пересчитывать каждый раз?

Answer (score 3):

Если вас этот вопрос волнует, обычно примерно делают так: имя файла берут как md5(file_contents).":".timestamp.'.'.extension и записывают таким образом:

1. скажем получилось имя файла 71725897ea80276ea3bbee6b63283a45:1379598536.jpg
2. создаем директории out_dir/7/1/7 (по первым трем значениям md5)
3. записываем файл как out_dir/7/1/7/725897ea80276ea3bbee6b63283a45:1379598536.jpg
4. в базу пишем 725897ea80276ea3bbee6b63283a45:1379598536.jpg
5. при обращении к файлу рассчитываем имя директории так-же как в пункте 2.

md5 можно заменить на случайную строку в случае больших файлов, timestamp можно преобразовать так-же в строку.

Comment: если я обращаюсь к файлу -- как я узнаю его contents чтобы получить его md5 и т.д. чтобы на основе его данных получить его contents И вернуть пользователю :) в базе первых трез цифер нет... чтото какаято фигня получается. или я недопонимаю чтото.

Comment: ага, недопонимаете, первые три цифры это первые три цифры имени файла... в базе мы храним имя файла. естественно пункты 1-4 при схоранение файла используются.

Answer (score 2):

[[@maxiimkoo](/users/14394/maxiimkoo)](/users/14394/maxiimkoo), если файл уже был открыт в системе (linux 2.6 (а м.б. и более ранние версии)), то его inode вполне может находиться в кэше (вместе с деревом имен каталогов к нему). В этом случае время доступа от количества файлов в каталоге слабо зависит.

Насколько помню, для представления структур файловой системы в ОЗУ в основном используются rb-tree (логарифмическое время поиска) и хэширование (время почти не зависит от размера таблицы).

А вот при первом open...

Каталог это же фактически файл на диске, содержащий имена объектов (максимальная длина имени 255 байт) и ссылки на их inode, он тоже может быть фрагментирован, а вот движение головок по диску операция ужасно медленная.

**На практике я бы не рекомендовал хранить больше нескольких сотен файлов (каталогов) в одном каталоге.**

С другой стороны (помню Ваш предыдущий вопрос с 7 млн. файлов), глубина иерархии каталогов естественным образом ограничена максимальной длиной полного имени файла (1024 байта вместе с разделителями).